# Does the order of tags matter?

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions

E.g. in  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/3248/revisions, the editors clearly applied significance to the ordering of tags (besides for adding more). But, does it matter at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stack Exchange engine automatically [orders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87527/179) the tags by popularity when a question is posted or edited, no matter what the author or editors do.

It must be, in your example, that [food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [blessing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blessing) took turns having more questions than each other over the years.